# Como hago para que solo multiplique numeros reales y imaginarios combinados

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++, arduino, esp32

Es Arduino, con un esp32, está conectada a una pantalla lcd i2c 20x4, el problema es que solo suma y resta números reales y imaginarios, y yo quiero que solo multiplique, ya sea todo reales o imaginarios o combinados entre si. Aparte que el resultado se dará después de escribir 4 valores.
El programa funciona, pero solo habria que cambiarle eso, es decir, el detalle que solo tiene que multiplicar y dividir. Si yo quiero multiplicar solo numeros reales, lo hará, si quiero solo dividir, lo hará y si quiero hacer todo eso combinado, tambien, y asi para numeros reales y imaginarios.
Intenté de muchas formas, pero no encontré solucion alguna

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 20, 4);
#define FILAS 4
#define COLUMNAS 4
byte pinesFilas[FILAS] = {13, 12, 14, 27};
byte pinesColumnas[COLUMNAS] = {26, 25, 33, 32};
char teclas[FILAS][COLUMNAS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', '+'},
  {'4', '5', '6', '-'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'B'},
  {'.', '0', 'i', '='},
};

Keypad teclado(makeKeymap(teclas), pinesFilas, pinesColumnas, FILAS, COLUMNAS);


String a, b, c, d;
bool dec = 0, img = 0, SR, SR2, SR3;
int N1 = 1, MUESTRES = 0;
double SUMAI, SUMAR, N1P1I, N1P1R, N1P2I, N1P2R, N2P1I, N2P1R, N2P2I, N2P2R;



void setup() {
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.blink();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Ingrese la operacion");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
}

void loop() {
  if (N1 == 1) {
    Num1();
  }
  if (N1 == 2) {
    Num1P2();
  }
  if (N1 == 3) {
    Num2();
  }
  if (N1 == 4) {
    Num2P2();
  }
  if (N1 == 5) {
    Calculo();
  }
  if (N1 == 6) {
    Resultado();
  }
}
void Num1() {
  char tecla = teclado.getKey();
  if (tecla != '\0') {
    if (tecla >= '0' && tecla <= '9') {
      a += tecla;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(a);
    } else if (tecla == 'B') {
      a.remove(a.length() - 1);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("            ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(a);
    }
    else if (tecla == '.') {
      char dec = a.indexOf('.');
      if (dec >= '0') {
        a += tecla;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(a);
      }
    }
    else if (tecla == 'i') {
      char dec = a.indexOf('i');
      if (dec >= '0') {
        a = 'i' + a;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(a);
      }
      else {
        a.remove(0, 1);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("           ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(a);
      }
    } else if (tecla == '+' || tecla == '-') {
      if (tecla == '+') {
        SR = 0;
      } else if (tecla == '-') {
        SR = 1;
      }
      N1 = 2;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.print(tecla);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
    }
  }
}
void Num1P2() {
  char tecla = teclado.getKey();
  if (tecla != '\0') {
    if (tecla >= '0' && tecla <= '9') {
      b += tecla;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
      lcd.print(b);
    }
    else if (tecla == 'B') {
      b.remove(a.length() - 1);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
      lcd.print("             ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
      lcd.print(a);
    }
    else if (tecla == '.') {
      char dec = b.indexOf('.');
      if (dec >= '0') {
        b += tecla;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(b);
      }
    }
    else if (tecla == 'i') {
      char dec = b.indexOf('i');
      if (dec >= '0') {
        b = 'i' + b;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(b);
      }
      else {
        b.remove(0, 1);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print("          ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(a);
      }
    }
    else if (tecla == '+' || tecla == '-') {
      if (tecla == '+') {
        SR2 = 0;
      } else if (tecla == '-') {
        SR2 = 1;
      }
      N1 = 3;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.print(tecla);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("           ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.print("           ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
      lcd.print("           ");
    }
  }
}
void Num2() {
  char tecla = teclado.getKey();
  if (tecla != '\0') {
    if (tecla >= '0' && tecla <= '9') {
      c += tecla;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(c);
    }
    else if (tecla == 'B') {
      c.remove(c.length() - 1);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("             ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(c);
    }
    else if (tecla == '.') {
      char dec = c.indexOf('.');
      if (dec >= '0') {
        c += tecla;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(c);
      }
    }
    else if (tecla == 'i') {
      char dec = c.indexOf('i');
      if (dec >= '0') {
        c = 'i' + c;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(c);
      }
      else {
        c.remove(0, 1);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("           ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(c);
      }
    }
    else if (tecla == '+' || tecla == '-') {
      if (tecla == '+') {
        SR3 = 0;
      }
      else if (tecla == '-') {
        SR3 = 1;
      }
      N1 = 4;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.print(tecla);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
    }
  }
}
void Num2P2() {
  char tecla = teclado.getKey();
  if (tecla != '\0') {
    if (tecla >= '0' && tecla <= '9') {
      d += tecla;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
      lcd.print(d);
    }
    else if (tecla == 'B') {
      d.remove(d.length() - 1);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
      lcd.print("           ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
      lcd.print(d);
    }
    else if (tecla == '.') {
      char dec = d.indexOf('.');
      if (dec >= '0') {
        d += tecla;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(d);
      }
    }
    else if (tecla == 'i') {
      char dec = d.indexOf('i');
      if (dec >= '0') {
        d = 'i' + d;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(d);
      }
      else {
        d.remove(0, 1);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print("           ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(d);
      }
    }
    else if (tecla == '=') {
      N1 = 4;
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("           ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("           ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.print("           ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
      lcd.print("           ");
      N1 = 5;
    }
  }
}

void Calculo(){
  if(a.indexOf('i') == '\0'){
    a.remove(0, 1);
    N1P1I = a.toDouble();
  }else{
    N1P1R=a.toDouble();
  }
  if(b.indexOf('i') == '\0'){
    b.remove(0, 1);
    N1P2I =b.toDouble();
  }else{
    N1P2R= b.toDouble();
  }
  if(c.indexOf('i') == '\0'){
    c.remove(0, 1);
    N2P1I= c.toDouble();
  }else{
    N2P1R =c.toDouble();
  }
  if(d.indexOf('i')== '\0'){
    d.remove(0, 1);
    N2P2I = d.toDouble();
  }else{
    N2P2R =d.toDouble();
 }
if(SR == 0 && SR2 == 0 && SR3 == 0){
  SUMAI= N1P1I + N1P2I+ N2P1I +N2P2I;
  SUMAR= N1P1R+N1P2R+N2P1R+N2P2R;
}
else if(SR == 0 && SR2 == 0 && SR3 == 1){
  SUMAI= N1P1I + N1P2I +N2P1I - N2P2I;
  SUMAR =N1P1R+N1P2R+N2P1R-N2P2R;
}
else if(SR == 0 && SR2 == 1 && SR3 == 0){
  SUMAI= N1P1I+N1P2I-N2P1I+N2P2I;
  SUMAR = N1P1R+ N1P2R-N2P1R+N2P2R;
}
else if(SR == 0 && SR2 == 1 && SR3 == 1){
  SUMAI= N1P1I +N1P2I-N2P1I-N2P2I;
  SUMAR= N1P1R+N1P2R-N2P1R-N2P2R;
}
else if(SR==1 && SR2==0 && SR3==0){
  SUMAI = N1P1I- N1P2I+N2P1I+N2P2I;
  SUMAR= N1P1R-N1P2R+N2P1R+N2P2R;
}
else if(SR==1 && SR2==0 && SR3== 1){
  SUMAI = N1P1I-N1P2I+N2P1I-N2P2I;
  SUMAR= N1P1R-N1P2R+N2P1R-N2P2R;
}
else if(SR== 1 && SR2 == 1 && SR3 == 0){
  SUMAI=N1P1I-N1P2I-N2P1I+N2P2I;
  SUMAR=N1P1R-N1P2R-N2P1R+N2P2R;
}
else if(SR=1 && SR2==1 && SR3== 1){
  SUMAI=N1P1I-N1P2I-N2P1I-N2P2I;
  SUMAR=N1P1R-N1P2R-N2P1R-N2P2R;
}
MUESTRES=1;
N1=6;
}
void Resultado(){
  if(MUESTRES==1){
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    if(SUMAR != 0 && SUMAI !=0){
      lcd.print("Resultado:");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.print(SUMAR);
      if(SUMAI <=0){
        lcd.print(SUMAI);
        lcd.print("i");
      }else{
        lcd.print("+");
        lcd.print(SUMAI);
        lcd.print("i");
      }
    }
    else if( SUMAR !=0 && SUMAI==0){
      lcd.print("Resultado:");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.print(SUMAR);
    }
    else if(SUMAR == 0 && SUMAI !=0){
      lcd.print("Resultado:");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.print(SUMAI);
      lcd.print("i");
    }
    else if(SUMAR==0 && SUMAI==0){
      lcd.print("Resultado:");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
      lcd.print("0");
    }
    MUESTRES = 0;
  }
  lcd.noBlink();
  if(MUESTRES == 0){
    char tecla = teclado.getKey();
    if(tecla != '\0'){
      if(tecla =='B'){
        MUESTRES = 0;
        a="";
        b="";
        c="";
        d="";
        SUMAR = 0;
        SUMAI=0;
        N1P1I=0;
        N1P1R=0;
        N1P2I=0;
        N1P2R=0;
        N2P1I=0;
        N2P1R=0;
        N2P2I=0;
        N2P2R=0;
        N1=1;
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("           ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("           ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print("           ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print("           ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Ingrese la operacion");
        lcd.blink();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola. Es c o c++? Si es c++, podrías probar agregar esto:

`#include <complex>`. Eso puede ser menos eficiente, pero más claro.

Comment: Este codigo utiliza C++, sabes como se puede hacer? porque intenté de mil formas pero no funciona, si sabes podrias hacerlo? porque es para un proyecto integrador. al menos un ejemplo, que pueda funcionar para implementar en el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Si la biblioteca `complex` existe, puedes basarte en un código como este:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> a, b, c, d;
    
    a = std::complex<double>(1,2);  // 1 + 2i
    b = std::complex<double>(3,4);  // 3 + 4i
    c = a*b;
    d = a/b;
    
    std::cout << "multiplicación " << c.real() <<" + " << c.imag() << "i" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "división " << d.real() <<" + " << d.imag() << "i" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes acceder a la parte real e imaginaria con `.real()` y con `.imag()`. También puedes sumar y restar números complejos de ese modo.